# vs2012 main.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: “********.hpp”: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I had a problem about vs2012. when I compiled my project , I got error message 
 "fatal error C1083: can't open file:“MultiWidgets\Application.hpp”: No such file or directory".
 however the file exist as shown in Figure.

how to fix it ? Thank you!

Comment: What figure are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably fix the Additional Include Directories as per this screenshot

[image: Additional include directories]

Comment: +1. And heading off the OP's next question, Make sure the folder that *contains* the MultiWidgets folder (i.e the parent folder of MultiWidgets) is added to this path; *not* the MultiWidgets folder itself, or you'll still have the same problem.